# Error Installing Haskell BitSet Package on Windows XP

Tags: haskell

I get this,

```
C:\Documents and Settings\IBM-User\Desktop\b>runhaskell Setup configure
Configuring bitset-1.4.5...
Setup: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: gmp
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
```

although, as Daniel Fischer pointed out, I seem to have `integer-gmp-0.4.0.0` installed here: `C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\2012.4.0.0\lib`

Trying the `--extra-lib-dirs` and `--extra-include-dirs` yielded the same result.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Hmm, iirc, on Windows, GHC comes with its own copy of GMP. I don't think trying to use two versions of the same library together in one programme is going to work too well. I don't know how you'd make cabal find GHC's GMP though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment -- how could I check if my GHC has a version of gmp?

Comment: If `ghc-pkg list integer-gmp` says you have the `integer-gmp` package, then you have a GMP installed and working. I'm not sure how it's done on Windows, it could be that you then have a GMP dll in the same directory as the GHC binary, worth looking there.

Comment: yes, I think you're right - looks like I have `integer-gmp-0.4.0.0` installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted an issue on the github repository and apparently Sergei fixed the bug. Hurray!